# Counterpart of dominating sets in graphs

Tags: graph-theory

A $t$-fold dominating set in a simple undirected graph $G$ with vertex set $V$ is a subset $D\subseteq V$ such that each vertex of $V\setminus D$ has *at least* $t$ neighbours in $D$.

I am interested in the counterpart: a (proper) subset $M\subset V$ such that each vertex not in $M$ has *at most* $t$ neighbours in $M$. Is there a name for such subsets? If there is, could you please give me some references to papers dealing with this type of questions?

I am studying such sets in order to produce subgraphs of a graph with high minimal degree.

I only know that if $D\subset V$ has the property that each vertex not in $D$ has *exactly* $t$ neighbours in $D$ are called $t$-fold perfect dominating sets. (Leastwise for $t=1$, it is quite common to call them perfect dominating sets.)

Comment: I have asked the same question on other platforms as well (such as graph theoretical conferences or seminars) but no one told me that this concept is known. Thus we decided to give it the name $t$-marginal set with Imre Hatala and Sam Mattheus in this paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2021.112320